# python perform transformation on nested(?) list values during a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am beginner at python but wanting to learn from the problems I encounter.

At the end of a wroking script I have this code (see below) that outputs in a `.txt` file a series of values:

`name, bcoords[i]*AT`.

The operation is repeated 4 times, until `counting > 3` is `true`

**what happens is this (pseudocode):**

- `open('solution_AT.txt','a')`
- `output.write(str(target[0]))`
- `output.write('\n')`
- `counting = 0`
- `output.write(name0,bccords0*AT)`
- `counting = 1`
- `output.write(name1,bccords1*AT)`
- `counting = 2`
- `output.write(name2,bccords2*AT)`
- `counting = 3`
- `output.write(name3,bccords3*AT)`
- `counting = 4`
- `(counting > 3)` is `true`
- `output.write('\n')`
- `counting = 0`

Instead of this, I would like to temporarily keep the values:

`bcoords0*AT`, `bcoords1*AT`, `bcoords2*AT`, `bcoords3*AT`

Because I want to perform some variable-interdependent mathematical operations on them.

**Namely, what I want to do is this (pseudocode):**

*first, perform math operations on variables* `bcoords`

- `a = bcoords0*AT / (1-bcoords3*AT-bcoords2*AT-bcoords1*AT)`
- `b = bcoords1*AT / (1-bcoords3*AT-bcoords2*AT)`
- `c = bcoords2*AT / (1-bcoords3*AT)`
- `d = bcoords3*AT`

*second, write the values in the same order as the code below, but with:* `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` instead of `bcoords0*AT`, `bcoords1*AT`, `bcoords2*AT`, `bcoords3*AT`

- `open('solution_AT.txt','a')`
- `output.write(str(target[0]))`
- `output.write('\n')`
- `output.write(name0,a)`
- `output.write(name1,b)`
- `output.write(name2,c)`
- `output.write(name3,d)`
- `output.write('\n')`

*A line of this output would have the structure:*

```
target[0], name0, a, name1, b, name2, c, name3, d \n
```

And... I don't find how to do that, any help is much appreciated!
Best

**Code:**

```
output = open('solution_AT.txt','a')

if tet_i == None:
    output.write(str(target[0]))
    output.write('\n')

else:
    names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
    sorted_indices = sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name])
    output.write(target[0])
    counting = 0

    for i, name in sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name]):
        output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bcoords[i]*AT))
        counting = counting + 1

        if counting > 3:
            output.write('\n')
            counting = 0
```

output.close()

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this question, it was easy, I found my solution there:

[python store variable in function and use it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910071/python-store-variable-in-function-and-use-it-later)

If any help, here's my new code:

```
output = open('solution_AT.txt','a')

if tet_i == None:
    output.write(str(target[0]))
    output.write('\n')

else:
    names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
    sorted_indices = sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name])
    output.write(target[0], 'none', '0', 'none', '0', 'none', '0', 'none', '0')
    counting = 0
    top = 0

    for i, name in sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name]):
        VAR1 = (bcoords[i]*AT)
        VAR2 = int(((bcoords[i]*AT)/(1-top))*65535)
        output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, VAR2))
        counting = counting + 1
        top = top + VAR1

        if counting > 3:
            output.write('\n')
            counting = 0
```